# Acer laptop has been slow since the battery died

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an Acer Aspire E15 E5-576G.
Weeks ago the battery suddenly died, it had been working fine before can could hold for more than 2 hours.
The charging led would be on for about 30 seconds or longer then off if I plug it in. Can't charge it whatsoever, it says "Battery not present".
So I guessed I could use it without a battery, but I was wrong. Now I'm experiencing stuttering in games despite having power plan set to maximum performance and everything else. FPS dropped to half of what it was before. I don't understand how this could happen.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: the laptop knows that the power supply provided with it can't provide enough power to sustain all components at full load. In such situation it will mostly use AC power, but compensate from battery for the deficit. If the battery is not present, the laptop puts power limits on components to make sure the power supply is always sufficient.